# struts 2 bean is not created

Tags: session, jpa, struts2, javabeans

At first some precondition to my question, I'm using struts2 + tiles2 + toplink. NO spring at all.

The simplest scenario - is to display list of entities on the page. To optimize resolving JPA's EntityManager I would like to create helper (JPAResourceBean) that implements lazy load of entity manager. For this purposes I'm going to use struts2's bean declaration:

```
<bean  name="myfactory" class="my.model.JPAResourceBean" 
       scope="session" optional="false"/>
```

Why bean is not instantiated neither in session? (I'm using s:property just for debug)

```
...
<s:property value="#session.myfactory" default="buka.1"/>
...
```

nor in plain bean list:

```
...
<s:property value="#myfactory" default="buka.2"/>
...
```

May be the second part of question is - how to resolve this bean from java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution.

The matter is struts using lazy load (resolve on demand) approach to instantiate beans, so my JPAResourceBean was successfully resolved when I've accessed it over following syntax:

```
ActionContext.getContext().getContainer().getInstance(JPAResourceBean.class);
```