# Why JPA injection not works on @PersistentUnit

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection, struts, toplink-essentials

It is continues of question ( [struts 2 bean is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570976/struts-2-bean-is-not-created) ) 
I'm using struts2 + toplink in my very simple web application under Tomcat. 
On the page I would like use iteration tag. That is why I've declared some factory (SomeFactory) that resolves collection of entities (Entity).
Per article: http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/usclient005.htm#CIHCEHHG 
the only thing I need is declaration:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="name_in_persistence_xml")
public class SomeFactory
{
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="name_in_persistence_xml")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
       assert(emf != null); //HERE every time it is null
       return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    public Collection<Entity> getAll()
    {
       return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Entity.findAll").getResultList();
}
}
```

What is wrong? May be i miss something in web.xml? How to pre-init toplink for web application to allow injection happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get anything injected by Tomcat which is not a Java EE container (and even with a Java EE 5 container, injection only works for managed components like servlets, filters, listeners, EJB, web service endpoints...). So you will have to create the `EntityManagerFactory` manually (typically in a servlet or a helper class) and get the `EntityManager` from it:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf  = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU_NAME);
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Note that creating an `EntityManagerFactory` is a costly operation and should not be done for each request. However, creating an `EntityManager` is not and you should get one for each thread. But in your case, I'd suggest to use the [struts2-persistenceplugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-persistenceplugin) to handle this.

> Thanks, but it seems [...] that Java EE is not mandatory to use injection [...] the Spring brings necessary engine for it.

Indeed. But you wrote ***"NO spring at all"*** in your other question and you didn't list any piece that could provide injection out of the box. Anyway, check out the  [struts2-persistenceplugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-persistenceplugin), it might be enough for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems (I mean 'seems' since I have not real knowledge about this) that Java EE is not mandatory to use injection. Looking at sample http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html - the Spring brings necessary engine for it. So could you explain: can I use xwork (that is already part of struts2) to implement injection in the same way as spring does?